# Django URL dispatcher explanations 301 and 302 code error

Tags: python, django, url, dispatcher

I'm a beginner with Django and I have a problem with the Django url.

The below text is my url file:

```
    path('<slug:menu_slug>/', views.home_menu, name='home-menu'),
    path('<slug:menu_slug>/<slug:section_slug>/', views.home_section, name='home-section'),
    path('<slug:menu_slug>/<slug:section_slug>/<slug:item_slug>/', views.single_item, name='single-item'),
```

When I request for example the url `guide/territory/` in my console obtain this output

```python
    "GET /en/guide/territory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11227
    "GET /en/guide/territory/undefined HTTP/1.1" 301 0
    "GET /en/guide/territory/undefined/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
    "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
    "GET /en/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26271
```

my question is why are there requests with `undefined`?

Thanks in advance for the response.

Comment: Something in your template - is causing the browser to make another request, but is passing "undefined" instead of the actual value. Since "undefined" is a type from JavaScript, I would guess that a JS script is to blame. But without seeing the script we can't tell why it's passing the wrong value.

Comment: You need to show your `views.py` also, specifically `views.single_item`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the problem is a javascript of the theme, if I doesn't import it, the problem disappears. Thanks!